# How can I forbid the installation of WPS office on my company computers?

Tags: windows, malware

WPS office has some dark patterns now. When a client sends a file to one of our employees, if they have WPS office on their phone (default on Huawei and Xiaomi phones and nobody ever changes defaults) they don't actually send the file but they send a link.

The link opens the file in a web preview and there are two prominent "download" buttons. Both are fake buttons that don't actually download the file but is an exe that will install WPS office in background without any user interaction.

Employees can distinguish a phishing or malware emails, but still I found WPS office installed on too many computers: this is unacceptable.

For installing it doesn't require elevated permissions, it can install with the lowest user level, but of course for uninstall it requires admin...

There's a way to forbid installing this malware? Maybe like a group policy that forces microsoft defender to always treat any files signed by "zhuhai kingston" as malware

Comment: How are you managing your desktops? Would blocking the WPS server via whatever you use for content filtering be an option?

Comment: +1, Interesting Issue !! Can you block the WPS Installation Hostnames in the Corp Server Firewall & User Client Firewall ? Can your mail server check the links and "warn" users ?? How is the phone download button installing on the computer ???

Comment: Would you be able to set your email server up to block emails sent by this service? Killing the messenger might not be great, but if people learn that emails sent that way never work then they might learn to do it the right way.

Comment: @Prem Good idea! The exe is hosted on wpscdn.com - blocking that on the company DNS server

Comment: @Mokubai It would be trivial to set a filter blocking all emails containing "https://kso.page.link/wps" or "https://eu.docworkspace.com" - but i think everyone would complain "the client sent the email in front of me but it's not arriving in my inbox". The problem is that when the app is "sharing" the PDF it transparently uploads it on their servers for an indeterminate amount of time (HUGE security and privacy issue!!!) and shares the link instead of just sharing the file itself.

Comment: I made a group policy to forbid the execution of wps_office_inst.exe (I wonder if wildcards are accepted? Because chrome will download it again with a number suffix) and blocked the CDN domain name (wpscdn.com) - already got a call "can't download the PDF this client sent me" - so i guess it worked

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the problem in my company:

In the beginning i blocked emails with a bounce if the default "wps link" was present, but clients weren't smart enough to read the error message (harmful link blocked) and they thought the address was wrong, and it wasted too much time on phone support troubleshooting that.

Then I made a group policy to block the execution of wps_office_inst.exe, but then now they add a random suffix, so it doesn't work.

So, now I added amino editor as a plugin to all the browsers (it's a plugin that adds a custom css to specified websites), and have this as custom css for `eu.docs.wps.com`

```
.open-wps {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.preview-footer {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.pdf-convert-footer {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.common-header {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.pdf-cmd-bar-container {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.kma-pdf-convert-header {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.k-jxm {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.login-guid-bar {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

all the dark patterns are now hidden (download doesn't actually download, in order to download you need to click a "print" button, but there are two of them, and one is fake), so my users don't get tricked into downloading and silently installing malware.

Additionally, i blocked `wdl1.pcfg.cache.wpscdn.com` in the router which is where the malicious exe is served. Can't block all `wpscdn.com` because the javascript that loads the real download buttons are stored there, and the page would only show the fake download buttons.